# How to upgrade java version on an Azure pipeline Microsoft-hosted agent?

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am setting up an Azure DevOps pipeline and I am running a jar (in one of the pipeline tasks) that needs a higher version of java than the one installed on the Microsoft-hosted agent used by the pipeline. How can I update the java version on the agent and ensure that this job (the one that requires a high java version) gets executed on this agent?

Comment: Hi @Arsany, is the answer below to use Java Tool installer task could help? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

If you need a certain runtime or runtime version you need you can either use one of the provided "* Installer"-Tasks by microsoft or write some powershell that installs stuff for you but the main thing is that you set this up as part of the pipeline.

You need the task "Java Tool installer" as one of the first steps in your pipeline. Reference -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops